# Website uses Port TCP 32767 and Port TCP 32768

Tags: service, port, penetration-testing

I am doing a vulnerability analysis of my website (school project). I found two ports TCP 32767 and TCP 32768. These are registered by filenet. All the information I could find is that Port TCP 32768 is named Hacker's Paradise.  What does this mean? What are the vulnerabilities of these ports?
Services running on these ports are filenet-powsrm, filenet-tms and nlockmgr.

Answer (score 2):

A computer needs to open ports to communicate with his surrounding net. Each and every software can theoretically use every port (with limitations).

The mentioned ports are nothing special either. The information you have (https://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-32768.asp) is just a reminder that in the past software called "HackersParadise" has been using this port on others machines. It does not mean that you right now have this trojan at your machine (you can check this with a antivirus-software).

You can check the vulnerability of ports with special tools (I use in Linux the nmap-portscanner). Normally - if not used at the moment - they are closed. If they are used by FileNet (messaging client) and you or somebody of the school has it installed, it is ok as well.

As a short note: many ports have been used in the past to get entrance to a machine. That is normal. That is why you use a firewall and several measures to keep bad code outside. As a safety measure you can report this to the technician. He can measure traffic, access and some more to decide if this is a bad port-access or just plain normal.

Comment: @Ackermann Bettina If you found the answer helpful please mark as correct and/or upvote my answer. Thx.